# Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality - failed on Android Studio 2.2

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

I have Android Studio version 2.2 and when I open a new project, it says in the Messages tab:

> Error:C:\Users\Rooprai.gradle\caches\2.14.1\scripts-remapped\settings_4a7gjv1r4bbxs9f9pza41diyj\9ejwtyixtds2dlx9q4hqm4iap\cp_settings57408229\cache.properties (The system cannot find the file specified).

At the top of the screen it says:

> Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly.

Build Gradle:

> ```
>   // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
> ```
>
> buildscript {
>       repositories {
>           jcenter()
>       }
>       dependencies {
>           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
>
> ```
>     // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
>     // in the individual module build.gradle files
> } }
> ```
>
> allprojects {
>       repositories {
>           jcenter()
>       } }
>
> task clean(type: Delete) {
>       delete rootProject.buildDir }
>
> buildTypes {
>       release {
>           minifyEnabled false
>           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
>       } }

Please help, the activity_main.xml won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the directory \Users\user\.gradle\caches\2.x.

You will find the directories scripts & scripts-remapped. Keep a backup of them and then delete them from the directory.

Retry gradle sync. It should work as it will generated new cache files.

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

add in your build.gradle

```
buildTypes {
release {
    minifyEnabled false
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
}
}
```

Sync gradle   then clean and rebuild project.it will work