# Android studio my gradle project sync failed

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i have some kind of problem in my gradle app, hope you can enlighten me i just downloaded that code and normally it shoulds compile fine but here it is ... 
thanks for time

I'm getting error: "Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. eiditing) will not work properly."

**build.gradle(module:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.usmans.songscloud"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id: "xxxxxxxx-e269-4dfb-8b48-357b707acdae",
                                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "108880509xxxx"]
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://dl.bintray.com/ayz4sci/maven/'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.cjj.materialrefeshlayout:library:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.ayz4sci.androidfactory:downloadprogress:1.0.1'
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+'


    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.+@aar'

    // Required for OneSignal, even if you have added FCM.
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+'

    // Required for geotagging
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+"
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:+'

    // play-services-analytics is only needed when using 8.1.0 or older.
    // compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:+'
}
```

Comment: search for your problem first and then if you didn't find answer then ask new question. check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41499863/gradle-project-sync-failed-basic-functionality-failed-on-android-studio-2-2).

Comment: i searched and i didnt find any solutions, i already tried that one it doesnt work for me mate

Comment: I have copied your code it's working properly in my android studio, check gradle offline mode.

Comment: one wild guess, you updated something in your Android Studio.

Comment: i updated whole android studio to 2.4 preview 3

Comment: thanks Mehran Zamani i gues there is some problem with the new version, i tried with the 2.3 it works just fine